# Index out of range [1] with length 0

Tags: arrays, go, indexing, iteration, runtime-error

I'm working ona little MUD in Go, and I'm trying to read a list of rooms with exits from a file.
I expect the code to iterate through the lines of the file, filing every line with the index 1 to the room ID, every line with the index 2 to the room Description and every line wit the index 3 to be used to fill in the room's links. However when I run the code, i get a panic: runtime error: indext out of range[1] with length 0. I've been mulling over this for two days with no luck, any help would be mucho appreciado.

Edit: tried initializing `r` with `r:= []*Room{}` but am still getting the same error.

```
    r:= []*Room{}
    roomdoc, err := readLines("/usr/go/src/gopherit/GopherIT/roomdoc.txt")
    if err != nil {
        return r, err
    }
    i := 0
    index := 1
    for _, str := range roomdoc {
        if i == 0 {
            r[index].roomInitId(str)
            i++
        }
        if i == 1 {
            r[index].roomInitDesc(str)
            i++
        }
        if i == 2 {
            vri := strings.Split(str, ":")
            v, ri := vri[0], vri[1]
            r[index].addLink(v, ri)
            i++
        }
        if i == 3 {
            index++
            i = 0
        }

    }
    return r, err
}
```

Comment: What is `MUD`? .

Comment: Multi-User Dungeon, a type of text-based server RPG. Check out CoffeeMud for an example.

Comment: You did not initialize `r`

Comment: @BurakSerdar Tried initializing r with `r = []*Room{]` still getting the same error

Comment: @Hermeneut do you expect `r[index]` to *grow* the slice?

Comment: @mkopriva Okay. Just read up on slices, 'cause I thought I was working with arrays (doh). How would I append an empty `Room` type to the slice to then fill in the fields of? I tried `r.append(roomInitId(str))` but that is def not the right answer. Also tried `r.append(r, r[index])` but that didn't work.

Comment: @Hermeneut btw shouldn't your `if`s be chained with `else`s? As it stands right now, all of the `if` conditionals will be `true` in the first iteration. (each `if` block increment the `i` a by that the next `if` condition is satisfied)

Comment: @Hermeneut it's difficult to suggest a solution because the problem description doesn't make much sense. You say things like "every line with index 1" and "every line with index 2", but by definition an index will be unique per line, hence there is no "every line" there's only one line with index 1 and one with index 2. Can you please try rephrasing the question so that it makes more sense?

Comment: @mkopriva, @burak-serdar Thank you guys! fixed it! needed to initialize `r` and use `r=append(r, &Room{})` The if/else problem also cropped up, but I fixed that too! Thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you doing is "Hey go make a variable r that is a slice of pointers from the Room Struct" r:= []*Room{}" and then using on the For, so is basic trying to access a position in memory that doesn't exist in that context.

So you need to append into that slice, like  `r = append(r,&Room{})`